# AngularJS only showing one list item at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**HTML**

```
<ul class="column__list">
    <li class="column__list--item" ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy:'name':false" data-ng-class="{active:taskIndex=={{$index}}}">
        <div class="column__list--expand fa" ng-click="expand = !expand" ng-class="{'fa-chevron-down': !expand, 'fa-chevron-up': expand}"></div>
        <div class="column__list--actions slide" ng-show="expand">
            {{ children }}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
angular.module('App.animate', [])
        .animation('.slide', function() {
            var NgHideClassName = 'ng-hide';
            return {
                beforeAddClass: function(element, className, done) {
                    if(className === NgHideClassName) {
                        jQuery(element).slideUp(done);
                        console.log('0');
                    }
                },
                removeClass: function(element, className, done) {
                    if(className === NgHideClassName) {
                        jQuery(element).hide().slideDown(done);
                        console.log('1');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I have the above which when clicked a div will slideDown and when clicked again will slideUp `.column__list--expand`

This works but what if I only wanted to have one `li` on show at a time and also update the `ng-class` too?

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mbvwqcv6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template to:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <ul class="column__list">
      <li class="column__list--item" ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy:'name':false" data-ng-class="{active:taskIndex=={{$index}}}">
        <div class="column__list--expand fa" ng-click="$parent.selectedTask = $parent.selectedTask == task ? null : task" ng-class="{'fa-chevron-down': $parent.selectedTask!=task, 'fa-chevron-up': $parent.selectedTask==task}">{{ task.title }}</div>
        <div class="column__list--actions slide" ng-show="$parent.selectedTask==task">
            {{ task.description }}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mbvwqcv6/1/)